# Solve side & angle of triangle from a median, side and angle

Tags: triangles

Given a Triangle ABC with 3 Angles ($A, B, C$) and 3 sides ($a, b, c$) and Median $ma$ (from $A$). like image below:

[image: Triangle Image]

Problem 1: If we know Angle $A$, length of median $ma$, and side $a$. Is it possible to find one more side ($b$ or $c$) or angle ($B$ or $C$) ?

Problem 2: If we know Angle $B$, length of median $ma$, and side $b$. Is it possible to find one more side ($a$ or $c$) or angle ($A$ or $B$) ?

Comment: I took a look to the triangle formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle and Median Formulas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry). However, All of them relating to a median and two sides. I only have one side and an angle... I also tried expanding the triangle to parallelogram
but no clue....

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than that. Which formulas do you think are applicable here? How do you relate an angle with its sides

Comment: Sorry, I hit enter. So, the comment is popped up incompletely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think big. Instead of trying to find just one line or one angle, try to find *all* of them. Or at least relate as many as you can.

For problem one, you know two sides and an angle. The other unknowns are the sides $b$, $c$ and angles $B$, $C$. You'll need at most a system of 4 equations. The law of cosines is useful here.

Triangle ABC gives
$$ a^2 = b^2 + c^2 + 2bc\cos A $$
Triangle ABM gives
$$ m^2 = b^2 + \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + ab\cos B $$

Triangle ACM gives
$$ m^2 = c^2 + \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 + ac\cos C $$

And of course
$$ A + B + C = 180^\circ $$

With $A$, $m$, $a$ known, you have 4 equations in $b,c, B, C$ which can be solved. You don't have to solve this, but it's clear that a solution exists for all 4 variables.

Problem 2 is very much the same, but with different unknown variables.